# How can i transform KML polygons in their 'mask' equivalent entities?

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have KML file and i want to and i want to grey out rest of the world and visible only my country. but KML is also not showing and How can i do like this http://www.vasile.ch/hacks/ft-mask/

[KML File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxx6cI-28pcvdDdrUU1zQ0NkNlU)

```js
function initMap() {
   var myLatLng = {lat: 19.0760, lng: 72.8777};    
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
       zoom: 5,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.4913, 78.9000),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       disableDefaultUI: true      
   }); 
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
       map: map,
       singleInfoWindow: false,        
   });
   geoXml.parse('India_KML.kml'); 
   google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml,'parsed', function() {
       geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "India"},function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
           } else {
               alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
           }
       });    
   })
}
window.onload = initMap;
```

```css
#map-canvas { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  position:absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 0;
  zoom:0.8;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?region=IN&libraries=places"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invert KML so that area outside of polygon is highlighted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538676/how-to-invert-kml-so-that-area-outside-of-polygon-is-highlighted)

Comment: How can i do with above pasted example? @geocodezip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the linked duplicate: [How to invert KML so that area outside of polygon is highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538676/how-to-invert-kml-so-that-area-outside-of-polygon-is-highlighted):

> Change your KML. Add an outer boundary to the polygon that covers the whole world. Make sure the winding direction of the outer polygon is opposite the winding direction of the inner polygon.

- [winding direction of initial polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/India_KML.kml) is positive, need to make the outerbounds wind negatively.

```
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>      
        <Folder>            
            <Placemark>             
                <styleUrl>#poly-A52714-1-77</styleUrl>

                <Polygon>
<outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>180,85 180,0 180,-85 90,-85 0,-85 -90,-85 -180,-85 -180,0 -180,85 -90, 85 0,85 90, 85 180,85
<!--
180,85 90,85 0,85 -90,85 -180,85 -180,0 -180,-85 -90,-85 0,-85 90,-85 180,-85 180,0 180,85 
-->
</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs>
<innerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>                            
                            <coordinates>
                               73.6523438,36.8796206,0.0 73.125,36.7036596,0.0 <!-- ... snip -->
                            </coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
</innerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
<!-- snip -->
    </Document>
</kml>
```

[example with "fixed" KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_nosidebar.html?lat=21.797758&lng=82.441406&zoom=4&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/India_KML_inverted.kml)

[image]

Comment: infowindow is showing on click of outside click how can i disable that thing?

Comment: `<Style id='poly-A52714-1-77-normal'>
   <LineStyle>
    <color>50000000</color>
    <width>1</width>
   </LineStyle>
   <PolyStyle>
    <color>50000000</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
    <outline>1</outline>
   </PolyStyle>
  </Style>
  <Style id='poly-A52714-1-77-heighlights'>
   <LineStyle>
    <color>50000000</color>
    <width>24.0</width>
   </LineStyle>
   <PolyStyle>
    <color>50000000</color>
    <fill>1</fill>
    <outline>1</outline>
   </PolyStyle>
  </Style>`